# C# SHA256 RSA Signing. How to take a string from byte[] sign?

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography, base64, sha256

I have to use some API, which service who has my certificate. They propably wants my sign to verify if it is the same with certificate on their server. Im not sure of that, but. In documentation it is instruction:

```
sign_base = 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">  

//big XML, but i can't paste it here, because of NDA i signed (with pen ;-)) 

</ds:Reference> </ds:SignedInfo> 

rsa_sha256(sign_base) = 
113c7ed1e66e1ef77c0857d418928bdf1d3bdf27b8d06c7...40d1c0a259733ad0b1b2
// its long hash so i made "..." it is 516 characters there. 

base64(rsa_sha256) =  ETx+0eZuHvd8CFfUGJKL3x073ye40Gx7mB0.... tCxsg==
//it is a base64 of rsa_256 hash above.
```

Inspired by SoF questions i tried to use `RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();` and then `var signed = provider.SignData(sign_base, CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("SHA256"));` but result gives me only `bytes[]`. When i decoded `bytes[]` to `UTF-8 string` result was unreadable "?????????..???" I can compare that with other signs, and do all stuff allowed by `RSACryptoServiceProvider()` but my question is:

They want to send this hash in request as parameter, so it is declared as base64 string. I have to send only base64 formatted message, but i have to count it first.

How to get string of this sign? Maybe there is mistake in my choices, and i am doing it wrong? If you give me help with different language than C# it will be helpfull too.

Comment: Cryptographic functions almost exclusively act on bytes. The encoding / decoding is commonly left to the user. Base 64 is only required if you need to treat the result as *text* rather than binary, like if you want to put it in an XML structure... So you have to use the encoding *or* you use a higher level API that provides XML DigSig - *which is a cryptography  standard* - out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well and provided that your signature is correct, once you have it as `byte[]`, you should be able to use `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] data)` using  [System.Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads).
Unlike what you did, you should be able to see a String looking like the example.